# Update from EntityListener - or is there a better way to achieve this?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have the following JPA Entities - Rule and Strategy. And I am would like it, so any update to a Rule will set the lastModified date of the Strategy. After many hours I discovered that I cannot call the entityManager from within a EntityListener.

My question, therefore, is
**how can I update the lastModified date in Strategy, when a Rule is updated?**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "strategy")
public class Strategy {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;



@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date modifiedDate;



@Table(name = "rule")
@EntityListeners({RuleListener.class})
public class Rule {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(/*optional = false, */fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="STRATEGY_ID"/*, nullable=false*/)  
private Strategy strategy;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `@PrePersist` and [`@PreUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html) for stuff like this. It looks like `Rule` has a direct reference to `Strategy` so you can put the `@PreUpdate` method there:

```
@Table(name = "rule")
@EntityListeners({RuleListener.class})
public class Rule {
  // ...

  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate() {
    strategy.setModifiedDate(new Date());
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can tell your relationship to [`cascade`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#cascade%28%29) updates to `Strategy` and put the `@PreUpdate` in `Strategy` instead (this way you can still change `modifiedDate` if `Strategy` is updated independently):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "strategy")
public class Strategy {
  // ...

  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate() {
    modifiedDate = new Date();
  }
}

@Table(name = "rule")
@EntityListeners({RuleListener.class})
public class Rule {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.UPDATE)
  @JoinColumn(name="STRATEGY_ID"/*, nullable=false*/)  
  private Strategy strategy;
}
```